# Riesz potential-inequality

Tags: lebesgue-integral

Does the following hold?

There is a $C>0$ such that

$$\left|\left|\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \frac{|f(y)|^2}{|x-y|} dy\right|\right|_{L^3(\mathbb{R}^3)} \leq C||f||^2_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)}$$ 
for all $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^3).$

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Let's introduce Riesz potential
$$
I_\alpha f(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{f(y)}{|x-y|^{n - \alpha}} \; dy.
$$
According to the Hardy-Littlewood-Sobolev frcational integration theorem if
$$
\frac{1}{q} = \frac{1}{p} - \frac{\alpha}{n},
$$
for $1 < p < n/\alpha$, then Riesz potential acts as a bounded operator from $L^p$ to $L^q$
$$
||I_\alpha f||_{L^q(\mathbb{R}^n)} \le c ||f||_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)}.
$$

Now just take $f^2$ instead of $f$ and set $q = 3$, $\alpha = 2$, $n = 3$, $p = 1$.

And everything seems correct, but wait... You **cannot** apply fractional integration theorem for $p = 1$! And the counterexample for this is famous as well: we need to take a characteristic function
$$
f = \chi_{(0,1)^3}
$$
Then for $|x| > 1$
$$
I_2 f(x) = \int_{(0,1)^3}\frac{dy}{|x-y|} \ge \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{|x|}
$$
So we have
$$
||I_2 f||_{L^3 (\mathbb{R}^3)}^3 \ge \frac{1}{2} \int_{|x| > 1} \frac{dx}{|x|^3} = \infty.
$$
On the other side
$$
||f||_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)} = 1
$$
as the volume of unite cube. So this inequality does not hold even for so simple function.

Comment: Powerful counterexample!